# Detect what files are being loaded by browser

Tags: javascript, file, load

I haven't found similar question here, so here it goes:

Can I detect files that browser is fetching from the server for a current page? Like images, javascript files and background images from css.

I couldn't find any API on MDN. I know that this wasn't possible couple of years ago and I wasn't following this particular issue.

It seems like quite useful feature, and I don't see security issues with it.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to do this with javascript, but you can open the network tab in the Chrome debugger and see all the resources requested by the page.

Comment: Yes, I know. So I thought I might have access to that through some API.

Comment: It looks like Chrome has access to some of this info for browser extensions (not regular browser pages) via the devtools interface: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_network

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for... well, I guess it's not time yet

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm just looking at possibilities. Preloader, app internet consumption optimization, javascript loader etc...

Comment: document.images, document.links, $("script['src'], video['src'], track['src'], audio['src']") should get you going. hardest is bg image refs from off-site CSS, but everything else you mention is easy.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you can use this now:

`var resource = window.performance.getEntries()[0];
console.log(resource);`

Comment: _how_ does this work? _why_ does this work? Please explain your answer.